# Setting up Elementary OS with VMware Workstation, cannot use unity?

Tags: virtualization

I'm trying to setup Elementary OS as a VM on my Windows machine, and I wanted to use VMWares Unity mode. However, every time I try to load it up, it says

```
The virtual machine cannot enter Unity mode because:

- Unity is not supported in Linux guests.
```

Yet I've seen others make this work with other Linux distros like Xubuntu. Does VMWare not support ElementaryOS?

I tried also installing the VMware tools as well but no luck...

Comment: FYI elementaryOS does not come with Unity, also Ubuntu just dropped Unity for Gnome

Comment: Ah not the desktop environment unity I was talking about here. Was talking about the mode on VMWare called Unity.

Comment: You are right, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware drop support for Unity with later Workstations, use VMware Player 7 and it works. https://communities.vmware.com/thread/518568